# Don't reference all vendored libraries shipped with cocoapods

Tags: xcode6, cocoapods, podspec, linker-flags

## Situation

I have a static Library Project which references a few other static Libraries.
To distribute my (company internal) Library I added a podspec file.
I added the third party libraries to the vendored_libraries like this:

```
spec.vendored_libraries = "dependencies/libraries/**/*.a"
```

and the libraries command like this:

```
spec.libraries = "AfariaSLL", "ClientHubSLL", "Connectivity", "CoreServices", "Datavault", "E2ETrace", "Logger", "MAFLogger", "MAFLogonManagerNG", "MAFLogonUING", "MAFUIComponents", "MAFUIHelper", "Parser", "PerformanceLib", "Request", "sqlcipher", "crypto", "MAFFormatters", "MAFLocaleAwareControls", "MAFZipHelper", "ssl", "xml2", "stdc++", "z"
```

When i install the pod to one of my projects, the *.a files are copied as expected and referenced within the Pods.debug.xcconfig and Pods.release.xcconfig files like this:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -all_load -stdlib=libstdc++ -l"AfariaSLL" -l"ClientHubSLL" -l"Connectivity" -l"CoreServices" -l"Datavault" -l"E2ETrace" -l"Logger" -l"MAFFormatters" -l"MAFLocaleAwareControls" -l"MAFLogger" -l"MAFLogonManagerNG" -l"MAFLogonUING" -l"MAFUIComponents" -l"MAFUIHelper" -l"MAFZipHelper" -l"Parser" -l"PerformanceLib" -l"Pods-SBBSMPLib" -l"Request" -l"crypto" -l"sqlcipher" -l"ssl"
```

Until here everything works fine.

## Problem

Not every Project needs all of the vendored libraries. So I tried to just reference the required libraries like this:

```
spec.libraries = "AfariaSLL", "ClientHubSLL", "Connectivity", "CoreServices", "Datavault", "MAFLogonManagerNG", "MAFLogonUING", "MAFUIComponents", "Request"
```

and hoped that it would have an impact to the `OTHER_LDFLAGS`. But unfortunately the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` remains the same. Even when i completely remove the `spec.libraries` line the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` don't change.

## Summary

How can i achieve that the third party libraries are copied to the projects but not all are referenced within the `OTHER_LDFLAGS`?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution I tried (and worked - but ist nowhere documented) is to create different podspec files for the possible scenarios. That means: different `spec.vendored_libraries` definitions for the different goals